# ¿Cómo dar permiso a un controlador, pero no a ciertas funciones? hook Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Soy nuevo en el mundo de Codeigniter y me gustaria saber como conceder permisos a usuarios a un controlador que tiene funciones como iniciar sesión, cerrar sección, actualizar datos de usuario ... pero si un usuario no inicia sesión que no pueda acceder a actualizar datos de usuario o cerrar sesión pero si iniciar sesión, atraves de hook Codeigniter.

Estaba pensando en algo asi pero no creo que se asi:

```
class Authenticate
{

    private $CI;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();

        if(!isset($this->CI->session)){  //Check if session lib is loaded or not
              $this->CI->load->library('session');  //If not loaded, then load it here
        }
        $session_user = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        $method       = $this->router->method;
        $controlador  = $this->router->class;

        if(empty($session_user) && $controlador != 'admin'){
            redirect('admin/login');
        }elseif (empty($session_user) && $method != 'update_profile') {
            redirect('admin/login');
        }
    }

    function loginCheck()
    {
        $session_userdata = $this->CI->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
        if($session_userdata['is_logged_in'] == TRUE)
        {
            echo "Valid User"; //it wont get inside this if
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

crea una función que compruebe si hay sesión abierta y ahí muestras el formulario según el estado de la sesión:

```
if( hay_sesion_abierta() ){
   //mostrar form edicion
   $this->load->view('modificar_datos');
}else{
   //mostrar form edicion
   $this->load->view('iniciar_sesion');
}
```

si quieres redireccionar a otra pagina usa algo asi:

```
if( hay_sesion_abierta() ){
    //mostrar form edicion
    redirect("modificar_datos");
}else{
    //mostrar form edicion
    redirect("iniciar_sesion");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionarlo la solucion esta en los hook, me cree uno de esta manera:

hook.php

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array( 'class' => 'Authenticate', 'function' => 'loginCheck', 'filename' => 'authenticate.php','filepath' => 'hooks');
```

authenticate.php

```
class Authenticate
```

{

```
private $CI;


function __construct()
{
    $this->CI =& get_instance();

    if(!isset($this->CI->session)){  //Check if session lib is loaded or not
          $this->CI->load->library('session');  //If not loaded, then load it here
    }


}

function loginCheck()
{
  $sess_id = $this->CI->session->userdata('username');
    $class = $this->CI->router->class;
    $method = $this->CI->router->method;
    if ($sess_id == FALSE && $class == 'admin') {

        //funciones permitidas del controlador admin

        if (in_array($method, array('login', 'secure_login', 'ajax_enviar_mensaje','ajax_enviar_respuesta', 'servidor_notificaciones'))) {

          return;

        }else {
           // si se intenta entrar en una función no permitida redirecciono a login
          return redirect(base_url('admin/login'));

        }
    }

}//login
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public function adminDashboard()
{
    //Validas que exista una sesion activa
    if (!isset($this->session->userdata['sess_data']['id_usuario'])) {
        //Si no existe sesion activa haces un redirect al login
        redirect(base_url().'Controlador');
    }
    //Si si existe una sesion activa colocas tu codigo
}
```